# Parse untagged sum type with aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I want to parse external json where `RequestItem` and `FolderItem` can show up in the same place. I came with the following encoding where each variant is defined as a separate data type:

```
data RequestItem = RequestItem { name :: String } deriving (Generic, Show)

data FolderItem = FolderItem { item :: [Item] } deriving (Generic, Show)

data Item
  = RequestChoice RequestItem
  | FolderChoice FolderItem
  deriving (Show)    

instance FromJSON Item where
  parseJSON = (\v -> asum [
    RequestChoice <$> (genericParseJSON defaultOptions v),
    FolderChoice <$> (genericParseJSON defaultOptions v)
   ]) :: Value -> Parser Item
```

Can this be simplified to a single data type definition, eliminating `RequestChoice` and `FolderChoice` ?

One restriction: I don't want to write parser by hand but rather use generic derivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [`UntaggedValue` option](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:SumEncoding):

```
data Item
  = RequestItem { name :: String }
  | FolderItem { item :: [Item] }
  deriving Generic

instance FromJSON Item where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions{sumEncoding = UntaggedValue}
```